# Android - Align dynamic text views for different screen comming from server

Tags: android, text, layout

I am trying to implement a greeting card like app so it have some edit text views which are coming  from server. I am also storing their margin on the server so that it could be placed at right position on the card. It works fine for current device and as expected it is not aligning properly for different screens. I have been working for two days to solve this issue, I have tried various math like, taking a factor for current device screen and multiply according to other device. Still i didn't got any working solution. 
I am using Relative Layout and margins are in dp.

Please help.

Comment: firstly if you could share some code snippet to understand it better.
Have a tried creating different layouts for different sizes layout and place them in the respective folders. eg. mdpi
-Why dont you try with Constraint Layout? 
- Im not sure how storing margins on the server will help as it should be in XML?

Comment: Hey, @Rohan thak you for your suggestion for using constrain layout. I was also think the same, my root layout is a constrain layout itself. I am using Relative layout for the text view because I also need drag and drop functionality which is not working in constrain layout.